# Reverse Current in N Channel Power Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, current-source, inductance, reverse-polarity, current-mirror

I am designing a bidirectional current source to drive a large (~60A) current through a large inductive load (100's mH) and facilitate very fast switching times (as close to an 1A/us as possible). My original design comprised of a pair of current mirrors, one using N type the other using P type power mosfets, with the load connected to a junction in between. Unfortunately P type power mosfets that can handle ~60A and withstand reverse voltages up ~1kV are unavailable, and if they were it is very unlikely they would have the same response characteristics as their N type partners, breaking the symmetry of my current source response. I was curious if it would be possible to replace a P channel power mosefet current mirror with an N channel setup running D to S current backwards

Comment: My gut tells me there is a better way - what are you trying to achieve from a higher perspective?

Comment: If you can maintain Vgs somehow, sure.

Comment: One issue: V=Ldi/dt.  You are aiming for di/dt of 1A/us or 1 million amps per second.  With 100's mH you would need 100,000's of volts.  You simply cannot change the current in a large inductor that quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible to get an NMOS, swap drain and source and use it as a PMOS then why would PMOS transistors exist ?

Also think about why an NMOS needs a **positive Vgs** to conduct while a PMOS needs a **negative Vgs**.

Another reason why you cannot simply swap drain and source of a Power MOSFET is that there's a diode between drain and source.

I suggest that you study the theory behind current mirrors. Current mirrors rely on transistors being identical and at the same temperature.

Power MOSFETs are also not suitable to build proper mirrors as they have very large W/L values and a small difference in Vgs can result in a large difference in current. Typically you need a feedback mechanism with a current shunt resistor to control the current through a Power MOSFET properly.

PowerFETs are designed for switching and have a low Rds so you do not suffer too much voltage drop when switching large currents. I consider 60 A a large current. Have you thought about what would happen if the MOSFET has to limit the current to a lower value (I assume that you want to limit the current since you're using a mirror).